# SQLite Create Table and Insert & Update Value

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I am studying at Udemy SQL course, I am stuck on the below problem. Could you help me how to solve? It is very difficult for me.

Here's the question:
The goal of this exercise is to find out whether each one of the 4 numeric attributes in `TemporalData` is
positively or negatively correlated with sales.

Requirements:

- Each example in the sample consists of a pair (Store, WeekDate). This means that Sales data must be summed across all departments before the correlation is computed.
- Return a relation with schema `(AttributeName VARCHAR(20), CorrelationSign Integer)`.
- The values of AttributeName can be hardcoded string literals, but the values
  of `CorrelationSign` must be computed automatically using SQL queries over
  the given database instance.
- You can use multiple SQL statements to compute the result. It might be of help to create and update your own tables.

Here's the sales table:

```
| store | dept | weekdate | weeklysales |

|1      | 1    | 2010-07-01| 2400.0     |
|2      | 1    | 2010-07-02| 40.0       |
```

Here's the temporaldata table:

```
| store | weekdate | temperature | fuelprice | cpi  | unemploymentrate|


| 1     |2010-07-01| 100.14.     | 2.981     | 125.1222 | 9.402

| 2     |2010-07-02| 99.13       | 3.823     | 129.2912 | 14.81
```

So, I wrote code like below. Could you give how to solve this question.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CorrelationGroup 
CREATE TABLE CorrelationGroup(
    attributName VARCHAR(30),
    CorrelationSign INTEGER
);
```

```sql
SELECT SUM(weeklysales)
FROM temporaldate t, sales s
WHERE s.weekdate = t.weekdate AND s.store = t.store ;
```

```sql
SELECT AVG(t.temperature) as 'temp', AVG(t.fuelprice) as 'fuel', AVG(t.cpi) as 'fuel', AVG(t.unemploymentrate) as'unemploymentrate
FROM sales s, temporaldate t
WHERE s.store = t.store AND s.weekdate = t.weekdate;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO CorrelationGroup VALUES ('Temp', 'The Value Of CorrelationSign');
-- 3 more
```

Comment: Your database representation is unhelpful. Could you provide an MRE according to the tag info you used https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: If you are learning SQL, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.